# How to set template variable <title> in Django?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-templates, django-views

I am very new to Django, trying to setup my first personal CMS website. Please apologize if it is obvious. I am transitioning from `PHP`, so it is little confusing at times.

I would like to set the title of the website "Dashboard|MCA Portal". The sitename comes from MySQL Database
MySQL query :

```
select value from options where `param`='sitename'
```

Any idea how to do it ?

Thanks
Kiran

Comment: x= options.objects.get(param='sitename') x.value get this values and send to template

Comment: You need to do the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/) before asking basic questions like this. You would define a model, query that model in the view, and send the data to the template - all of which is described in that tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass title value to HTML template by 2 ways:

1) Override View get_context method where you query value from database and pass like my example (python 3.6):

```
class MyView(TemplateView):
  template_name = '...'
  ....
  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    title = ...  # query from database here
    data['title'] = title
    return data
```

2) Disadvantage of 1 method - you should manually implement query inside every View or implement BaseView and inherit all others Views in your project. Also you can implement **context processor**, see example below:

```
# file <project_root>/<app_dir>/context_processor.py
def app_context(request):
  # query from database
  title = ...  # query from database here
  return dict(site_title=title)

......................
# file <settings_dir>/settings.py
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': {
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
    },
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            '<app_package>/context_processor.app_context'
        ],
    },
},
```

]

Advantage of that method - variable *site_title* is accessable in all templates of context processor django application

See official doc **Writing your own context processors** here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/api/